# how do i stop repeat calls to java paint() replacing the last one?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I create a window with a panel with custom panel class  and paint circles on it based on array data. How do I get both sets of circles to stay on screen?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class DataPaint extends JPanel {
    static int offsetY = 0;
    int leftX = 20;
    int[] guessColours;
    Color purple = new Color(155, 10, 255);
    Color pink = new Color(255, 125, 255);
    Color[] Colours = { Color.blue, Color.cyan, Color.green, Color.orange,
            pink, purple, Color.red, Color.yellow };

    public DataPaint() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paintClues(int[] guessColours) {
        this.guessColours = guessColours;
        offsetY += 30;
    }

    // naive attempt to make it work !!!!
    // what is diff between paintComponent and paint?
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paintComponent(g);
    }

    // paint circles based on array data
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (int i = 0; i < guessColours.length; i++) {
            g2.setPaint(Colours[guessColours[i]]);
            g2.fillOval(leftX + (i * 30), offsetY, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    // create window with panel and paint circles on it based on array data
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("data paint");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);

        DataPaint panel = new DataPaint();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        int[] cols = { 2, 4, 5, 3, 6 };
        int[] cols2 = { 1, 3, 7, 3, 4 };
        // the second call replaces the first call on the panel?
        panel.paintClues(cols);
        panel.paintClues(cols2);

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry about the link, i tried posting the code on this site but  i couldn't get it past "quality control". it  seemed to be formatted ok though ?

Comment: The quality filter probably isn't complaining about your code (unless you didn't indent it, which you can do by selecting it and pressing the "{}" button in the edit toolbar); it's complaining about you posting a lot of code and no explanation. You should **explain more about what you're trying to accomplish.** I've edited your question to inline the code and put your actual question in plain text, not in the code.

Answer (score 3):

You don't stop it. The way Swing, and most GUI frameworks, work is that the `paintComponent` method or its analogue is always supposed to *draw everything from scratch*.

There are several reasons for this. One is is that if the window were resized, or any other sort of layout change occurred, or if the data-set being drawn changed in a complex way, you will need to be able to redraw anyway. Also, some window systems do not even store what is drawn in the window permanently, so you need to be able to redraw if your window is covered then uncovered. It is possible to have a component which has a permanent image that you can draw into, but that is not the usual way to do things and is less efficient unless you're writing, say, a paint program.

Change your data structures so that you keep all the information, and write your `paintComponent` so that it **draws everything you want on screen every time it is called**.

(There are refinements to make this efficient for partial updates of complex graphics, but you don't need to worry about those yet, as this is such a simple case. If you *did* need to do this, you would ask Swing to repaint a small region of your component (such as with `JComponent.repaint(Rectangle r)`; it would then automatically prohibit drawing to areas outside that region while it calls your `paintComponent` method. That works fine to prevent flicker and save some filling work; then if it really matters for efficiency, inside paintComponent you compare that clip region (`Graphics.getClip()`) to what you're drawing and skip everything that doesn't intersect. But you really shouldn't worry about that yet for this simple case. First get your code **working** and **using Swing correctly**, *then* optimize if it matters.)

In your particular example, which I take it is intended to be a Mastermind game (you should mention that up front to help us read your code), put `cols` and `cols2` into an `int[][]` field of DataPaint, and then use a loop inside of `paintComponent` to read every sub-array in that array and paint all of them.

Comment: i thought about storing the arrays but it seems a bit clunky. what if i was updating using a large number of arrays: wouldn't memory start getting  clogged up a bit. i thought stuff stayed on screen until u painted over it rather than being replaced by the next thing. can't i tell the paint method just to paint an area of the panel instead of the whole panel. java can do this i think?

Comment: @Gimli I've added info on how you would do that (see the parenthetical paragraph). But don't worry about doing that here; this is an extremely simple program which does not need such optimizations, and trying to implement that can produce more confusing bugs.

Comment: thanks for that Kevin. i've been busy taking your advice!!. Took the 'paint everything again' option using arrayList of arrays. Nearly there but boy, java painting  is really fiddly. Come back Flash all is forgiven.
Not sure my middle aged brain can cope with this kind of thing anymore. Where's that 12 year old malt i've been saving...
re mastermind: well spotted, i know its a simple game but thought it would be a good learning project. only started java in february.